# Evaluating $~\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin^{m-1}x}{(2+\cos x)^m}~dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

How to find the following definite integral:

> $$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin^{m-1}x}{(2+\cos x)^m}dx$$

I have done up to:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin^{m-1}x}{(2+\cos x)^m}dx=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{2^{m-1}\sin^{m-1}x/2~\cos^{m-1}x/2}{(3-2\sin^2x/2)^m}dx$$

Now, substituting $\sin^2x/2=z$, we have:

$$\int_0^1\frac{2^{m-1}z^{m/2-1}~(1-z)^{m/2-1}}{(3-2z)^m}dz$$

The numerator comes in the form of the [beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)... but what to do with the denominator ?

Help needed. Thank you !

Comment: For $m>0$ and $a>1$, we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin^{m-1}x}{(a+\cos x)^m}~dx ~=~ \frac{B(1/2,~m/2)}{(a^2-1)^{m/2}}~.$

Answer (score 2):

The defined integral can be expressed thanks to the Incomplete Beta function (given by Lucian) or Gauss hypergeometric function. In case of integer $m$, an explicit form with Gamma function can be derived, which reduces to factorials if $m$ is even :

[image]

Comment: Actually, you don't need all that. After substituting $\theta=\tan\dfrac x2,$ just let $\theta^2=3t^2$, and $u=\dfrac1{1+t^2},$ which will automatically yield the famous integral expression for Euler's beta function.